# TypeError: unbound method _get_tests() must be called with Loader instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, object

In the following code, "_get_classes" method works fine but "_get_tests" throws the above mentioned error. What am I doing wrong here?

```
def my_func():
     x = Loader._get_classes("test","number") # This works fine

     y = Loader._get_tests("abc","def","ghi") # This does not work



class Loader(object):
    def _get_classes(f, prefix_class_name=None):
         #code here

    def _get_tests(self, module_name, test_class, prefix_test_name):
         #code here
```

Comment: Are you sure the _get_classes() method works fine?
    x = Loader._get_classes("test","number") # This works fine
TypeError: unbound method _get_classes() must be called with Loader instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this: [unbound method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473184/unbound-method-f-must-be-called-with-fibo-instance-as-first-argument-got-cla)

You have to create an instance of class `Loader` to call method `_get_tests`, Example:

```
loader = Loader()
loader._get_tests("abc", "def", "ghi")
```

because this method has `self` in parameter. It means refer instance of class. Method `_get_classes` does not have `self` in parameter so it works fine without instance.

Comment: You can call the 'self' parameter anything you like, it's just a convention that it be called self.