# Why self is used in this function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, parameters, self

Why do I need to write `self` in this code despite it works?

But with my instructor, it didn't work and gave him an error mean that function doesn't take a parameter and you gave it one it happened when he took an object and he solved the error my placing self as an argument in `open_door()` and `close_door()` functions but the error didn't happen to me

```
class ferrari_2018():
   color='red'
   def open_door():
      print('open door')
   def close_door():
      print('close door')

x=ferrari_2018
x.open_door()
```

Comment: This code here has multiple problems, like you never calling the constructor, and having bad indentation. Please fix it so we know what code we're actually talking about.

Comment: Actually, the former is your problem. `x=ferrari_2018` should be `x=ferrari_2018()`.

Comment: You should read this, it will answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26789355/2241241

Answer (score 0):

```
color='red'
```

creates a class variable named color, so this variable is shared by all instances of the class Ferrari_2018.

With this code, you can't have 2 Ferraris with differents colors.

I imagine that you want to affect a custom color to each car.
So you need an instance variable, not a class variable :

```
class ferrari_2018():
  def __init__(self, color):
    self.color = color
```

With that, you can write :

```
x1 = Ferrari_2018('blue')
x2 = Ferrari_2018('yellow')
```

where x1 has its own attribute color (which is blue), and x2 has its own also.